# Spring Authorization server - limit a client to a specific resource server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have two RegisteredClients(and two resource servers):

```java
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient spa1 = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId("client1")
        ...
        .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:3000/authorized")
        ...
        .build();
    
    RegisteredClient spa2 = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId("client2")
        ...
        .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:3001/authorized")
        ...
        .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(spa1, spa2);
}
```

When I obtain *access_token* as **client1**, I can access endpoints in both resource servers.
I need **client1** to be able to access only **resourceServer1**, and **client2** to access **resourceServer2**.

I went through the docs and source code, but I cannot find a way to configure the client to be able to access only certain resource.
I think this was possible in spring security by doing:

```java
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder clientBuilder = clients
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("client1")
        .resourceIds("resourceServer1")
        ...
```

Is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by means of the `aud` claim in the access token.

The client will send the intended audience to the authorization server when it requests an access token, and each resource server must make sure to validate that the `aud` claim in the access token contains the resource server's ID.

If you use Spring Boot's Resource Server starter I think you can configure the audience ID with the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences` property (read more about it [here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerProperties.java#L82))

Otherwise, you'll have to look into configuring your own `JwtDecoder` with its own `JwtValidator` (which is what validates the JWT claims.)